# Why does powershell not accept my hand edited CSV

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Everything in my Powershell script works as intended, however if I take an exported CSV and remove several rows and colums from it that are not necessary in the script, it will tell me the fields I left untouched are null.

Here is the script I am running, it only needs 2 fields, DistinguishedName and SamAccountName.

```
ipcsv C:\Users\####\####\EditedCSV.csv | select-object DistinguishedName,SamAccountName | ForEach{
Rename-adobject $_.DistinguishedName -NewName $_.SamAccountName -WhatIf -Confirm:$false
}
```

I start with:

```
SamAccountName C GID DestinguishedName WhenCreated Description CN
```

And change it to:

```
SamAccountName DestinguishedName
```

does it not accept a csv that people have messed with, or is there some special trick I'm supposed to do when modifying data myself?

Comment: 99% of the time the issue is with the CSV being formatted incorrectly (e.g. trailing commas, unquoted strings, bad headers, etc.). In this case, you will have to include some sample of your CSV in order to troubleshoot as the code looks ok. And, (shhh) the "trick" to modifying CSV files: use Excel to open and save as CSV. Excel will make sure that the format is correct, and all characters are escaped properly, etc.

Comment: your CSV file is apparently _space_ delimited. you did not tell `Import-CSV` to use anything other than the default comma delimiter.

Comment: Is “DestinguishedName” a typo? The second letter in that is “e”, but maybe you mean “DistinguishedName”?

Answer (score 2):

There is a high possibility you are corrupting the CSV structure in your efforts to delete some information, although, it's impossible to say unless you were to share the CSV file you are working with.

(Also I am not sure if your typo is isolated to here, but make sure you have it as *"DistinguishedName"* not *"DestinguishedName"*).

A proper CSV file, in similar context to your question, would have the format:

```
SamAccountName,DistinguishedName
Robert,Bob
Samantha,Sam
Julianna,Juli
```

Where ***"Robert","Samantha" and "Julianna"*** correspond to the ***SamAccountName*** property- and ***"Bob","Sam" and "Juli"*** correspond to the ***DistinguishedName***  property.

Answer (score 1):

CSV files should be the same regardless of how the file was generated.  I've hand-edited literally thousands of CSV files without issue.  CSV files are a sub-type of Delimited Text Files, using a comma for the Field Delimiter and a double quote for the Text Delimiter, like this:

```
"Field1","Field2","Field3","Number1"
"Text1","Text2","Text3",7
"MoreText1","MoreText2","MoreText3",14
```

The examples you listed do not have any commas in them, so that might be why they are not being recognized as .CSV data.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
ipcsv -delimiter "<delimiter>" "filename.csv"
```

where <'delimiter'> is one of [, ; | `t ]

Answer (score 0):

I opened it in notepad compared to Excel, and I now see that the formatting was messed up. after correcting it through that I can now get it to function as expected.